# How to play internal sound files from iOS/iPhone in my app?

Tags: ios, audio

I am trying to use the internal sound files such as alarm, siren etc.. in an app I am trying to code. Basically when I turn a switch on, I want one of the internal sound files of my choosing to play.

I am currently using WAV's in the project file to do this, but I would like to use the internal sound files on iOS.

How can this be done/accessed?

Comment: could be a problem. You only have the permission to use the stuff from you app directory. But you could use `<AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>` for some standard sounds like: `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(0x450);`

Comment: Is there a list of sound values I can use?

Comment: of course. Look [here](https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the iOSSystemSoundsLibrary like: `<AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>`.
The way it works is: `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (1003); // SMSReceived`.
The list of sound and the examples "How to use" you can find at the page: [TUNER88](https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary).